# Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, rider, jetbrains-rider

I'm building a Xamarin app with JetBrains Rider. When I start typing an Entry-field or a SearchBar (in the iOS-simulator), the console gives me a huge amount of the same errors. It's so much that it is hard debugging my code. It only happens while using the iOS Simulator, not Android. The Simulator keeps doing it's job, it won't crash.

I'm using a MacBook Pro M1 2020 with Rider 2022.

This is the error I get with each keyboard-pressure:

```
2022-06-01 11:29:54.369366+0200 MyApp.iOS[50944:420356] [db] _LSSchemaConfigureForStore failed with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xde692fe4 74cb27a9 46141ef2 d51b2967 ... 1bf15bf0 1946d147 }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xb5aceade 20f27303 c39ab815 65e94ec7 ... cd950a70 602e0a75 }}
2022-06-01 11:29:54.369767+0200 MyApp.iOS[50944:420356] [db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore, ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xde692fe4 74cb27a9 46141ef2 d51b2967 ... 1bf15bf0 1946d147 }, _LSLine=405, WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xb5aceade 20f27303 c39ab815 65e94ec7 ... cd950a70 602e0a75 }}
```

Someone knows how to fix this so I can use Console.Writeline again?
Or does someone know how to ignore this error in the console in Rider?

I don't know if it has something to do with this, but when I build my project I also get this warning (once):

```
objc[50944]: Class _PathPoint is implemented in both /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 15.2.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore (0x12cb19e30) and /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 15.2.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI (0x16688f8b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[50944]: Class _PointQueue is implemented in both /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 15.2.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore (0x12cb19e08) and /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 15.2.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInputUI.framework/TextInputUI (0x16688f8e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=failed+with+error+Error+Domain%3DNSOSStatusErrorDomain+Code%3D-10817+site%3Adeveloper.apple.com&rlz=1C9BKJA_enUS889US890&hl=en-US&biw=1080&bih=695&sxsrf=ALiCzsbjYbAvCGlPi4ExupBZP3-rTLseHA%3A1654102323412&ei=M5mXYsvXGKquptQPyJO--AE&oq=failed+with+error+Error+Domain%3DNSOSStatusErrorDomain+Code%3D-10817+site%3Adeveloper.apple.com, multiple issues on M1 with simulator. Eventually Xcode updates by Apple fix the problems. I doubt there is a way to avoid. Can use `\n`s in WriteLine, blank lines, to make your messages a bit easier to find.

Comment: Thanks! For now I changed the cw-shortcut to give a Debug.WriteLine() in stead of Console.WriteLine(). Not the best solution, but workable for now